# Remove unwanted part of strings in a column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that looks like this

```
        Message

0       Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 3410
1       Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 4206
2       Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 3433
3       Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 4229
4       Position.cpp:438] <AGVPOS> 602, 7787.496, -920...
```

I would like to get rid of the part that starts from the beginning of the string until "] ".

I have tried to do it myself using this.

```
df['Message'] = df['Message'].astype("str")
df['Message'] = df['Message'].apply(lambda x: x[ x.index(']') :])
```

But I get this error : ValueError: substring not found

Is there a way to fix this one or just some other more efficient way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['Message'] = df['Message'].replace('^.*\]\s*','', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.replace`:

```py
df["Message"] = df["Message"].str.replace('^.*?\]\s*', '')
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKOaej/1) showing the logic is working.