# What are the functions of ^.*?\]\s* in Pandas / Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to find out more about removing part of a string in a column and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472124/remove-unwanted-part-of-strings-in-a-column-with-pandas/70472160#70472160)

in summary the OP wants to get rid of the part that starts from the beginning of the string until "] ".

```
        Message

0       Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 3410
1       Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 4206
2       Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 3433
```

and one of the response is:
`df["Message"] = df["Message"].str.replace('^.*?\]\s*', '')`

my question is - what are the functions of the ^, . , *, ?, , s, * in the parenthesis? I can't figure out how those symbols mean 'remove everything up to the close bracket'.

Google search keeps showing python operators and doesn't look relevant to the uses in .replace(). a link to a page explaining these would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that linked answer includes a "regex demo" and the [relevant docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) refer to patterns/regexes/`re.sub`.

Comment: Also, in the "regex demo" of the linked answer there's a snippet called "EXPLANATION" with a detailed explanation of how this particular regex works.